# How to add dotfill for the chapter in tableofcontents in book style?

Tags: table-of-contents, books

I am using the following codes to create a file which has number of pdf files inserted.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@dotsep{300}
 \makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline{chapter}{name of the first paper}{10}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\textit{Author of the first paper}}{}}
\includepdf[pages=2-last]{preface1}




\addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline{chapter}{Second paper }{3}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\textit{Author of the second paper }}{}}
\end{document}
```

My output for the table of contents is like this...

[image]

### My Requirement:

I want a dotfil for my chapter not for the section.
That dotfill has to be there for the title of the paper but not to the authors.

how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not compile for me because it depends on an external file, but you can load the `tocloft` package and then add the commands:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\hfill}
```

The first one adds the dots for the chapters, the second one (sections) has no dots, however there's a `\hfill` to fill the space between the section title and the number. Removing this last command would "justify" the title across the page width, which is not desirable.

Comment: kindly add some pdf file instead of preface1 and compile and check..it is giving error when I am loading `tocloft`. @alenanno